# What kind of microphone is being used by talkshow hosts?

Tags: audio-recording, microphone

Something similar to what this guy is wearing on his tie: [image]

Comment: lol, "this guy".  Also, it's called a lapel mic.  Give it a search.  You'll get a bunch of hits :)

Comment: @Josh, do you want to make this an answer? It's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I might also suggest rewording the title/body, to steer clear of the VTC.  As straight up shopping questions are OT, you might rephrase as a question about what kind of mic is in use here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "guy" is wearing a lapel mic.  Also known as a lavalier mic.  A quick excerpt from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapel_mic):

> A lavalier microphone or lavalier (or lav or lapel mic) is a small
>   electret or dynamic microphone used for television, theatre, and
>   public speaking applications, in order to allow hands-free operation.

With search terms in hand, you'll find many resellers.  Good luck :)